# SQL Server 2012 - Could not find an entry for table or index with partition ID xxxxx

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I noticed this morning strange behavior with a full text index which led to me finding the following issue when doing a `DBCC CHECKDB('MY_DATABASE')`:

> Msg 602, Level 21, State 30, Line 1
>   Could not find an entry for table or index with partition ID 72057607797997568 in database 8. This error can occur if a stored procedure references a dropped table, or metadata is corrupted. Drop and re-create the stored procedure, or execute DBCC CHECKDB.

This issue also shows itself when trying to drop the FullTextCatalog (as I think this error is somehow linked with the FullTextIndex in some way).

I've applied the Cumulative Update 7 to SQL Sever 2012 as some posts I've read suggest this is an issue with SQL Server itself but to no avail.

The partition doesn't seem to exist either based on no rows being returned when I run the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.partitions 
WHERE partition_id = 72057607797997568
```

I believe this issue is preventing me from rebuilding my FullTextIndex which seems to be corrupted (search results not returning what they should). Does anyone know how to solve it?

SQL Version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP2-CU7) (KB3072100) - 11.0.5623.0 (Intel X86)
>   Jul  9 2015 12:12:26
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>   Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: ) (WOW64)

Comment: See if it is connected with [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/670808/filtered-index-on-a-temp-table-in-a-stored-proc-can-result-in-a-error-602) somehow

Comment: Saw that earlier - Don't think so as my error isn't showing when executing a stored proc. The error occurs when trying to rebuild the full text index or running DBCC CHECKDB

Comment: Recommend that you migrate this question to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi @tabAllerman - How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer to recover from this problem. We initially tried to restore from Log files to the last good backup, but it turned out that one of the log files re-introduced the problem. The eventual fix was to restore some data from the log files and the rest using RedGate Data Compare